# How to model monitoring infrastructure using JSON-LD syntax?

Tags: monitoring, semantic-web, ontology, json-ld

Is there any well known standardized ontology for monitoring resources? I am working on a open-source monitoring platform and we'd like to model the inventory using the concepts of semantic web.

some entities we currently use:

- Resource
- Tenant
- Environment
- ResourceType
- Metric
- MetricType

relations:

- contains
- defines
- owns

Is there any standard close to this nomenclature?

Answer (score 3):

While I'm not aware on an ontology that contains all the concepts you enumerated you might wanna try LOV to search for vocabularies that contain some of the concepts: http://lov.okfn.org/dataset/lov/

Comment: nice. this is really helpful